# how to fix CSS input type=submit not show in my form?

Tags: html, css, button

My CSS for `<input type="submit">` not show in my form. I use external CSS for write this. But if i write inline CSS is working and button submit is change. What the problem?

Comment: Without some code and context it's impossible to help you. Please show some code, your CSS file, HTMl where you link it and so on.

Comment: There are a few possibilities I can predict.
1. The selector is not correct.
2. CSS is getting overwritten by another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any class names you can use this

```
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It's helpful for new devs to mention that you're referring to the CSS code that will help target the submit button